# How to remove unwanted space in this table?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a flow indicator bar in the form of:

```
Step 1 > Step 2 > Step 3
```

,I use table to do that, and the follow html did almost exactly I want:

```css
.concave{
  border-left:1em solid transparent;
  border-top:1em solid orange;
  border-bottom:1em solid orange;
}

.middle{
  background-color:orange;
}

.convex{
  border-left:1em solid orange;
  border-top:1em solid transparent;
  border-bottom:1em solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" style="font-size:30px;">
  <tr>
    <td class="concave"/>
    <td class="middle" style="width:25%;">Step 1</td>
    <td style="max-width:0.5em;"><div class="convex"/></td>
    <td class="concave"/>
    <td class="middle" style="width:25%;">Step 2</td>
    <td style="max-width:0.5em;"><div class="convex"/></td>
    <td class="concave"/>
    <td class="middle" style="width:50%;">Step 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but there is still some unwanted spaces in the table, how can I remove that? I tried:

```css
.concave{
  border-left:1em solid transparent;
  border-top:1em solid orange;
  border-bottom:1em solid orange;
}

.middle{
  background-color:orange;
}

.convex{
  border-left:1em solid orange;
  border-top:1em solid transparent;
  border-bottom:1em solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" style="font-size:30px;margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
  <tr>
    <td class="concave"/>
    <td class="middle">Step 1</td>
    <td style="max-width:0.5em;"><div class="convex"/></td>
    <td class="concave"/>
  </tr>
</table>
```

which sets both margin and padding of table be 0px, but still have some unwanted spaces.

Comment: Why using table for this? If it's not a e-mail template, wouldn't it be better to use Flexbox instead?

Comment: Also, please don't use the trailing slash in non-empty HTML tags like `<td>` and `<div>` — it doesn't "self-close" them and is just ignored (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3558200/2533215), and the layout doesn't break here only because `<td>`s are auto-closed before the next opening `<td>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `cellpadding="0"` to your table element. Try this.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-size:30px;">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the vertical white line separating `.middle` and `.convex` by adding `margin-left:-1px` to `.convex` as follows. This will move `.convex` one pixel to the left.

I also closed off the last step with the same width so you can see them together.

```css
.concave{
  border-left:1em solid transparent;
  border-top:1em solid orange;
  border-bottom:1em solid orange;
}

.middle{
  background-color:orange;
}

.convex{
  border-left:1em solid orange;
  border-top:1em solid transparent;
  border-bottom:1em solid transparent;
  margin-left:-1px;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" style="font-size:30px;">
  <tr>
    <td class="concave"/>
    <td class="middle" style="width:25%;">Step 1</td>
    <td style="max-width:0.5em;"><div class="convex"/></td>
    <td class="concave"/>
    <td class="middle" style="width:25%;">Step 2</td>
    <td style="max-width:0.5em;"><div class="convex"/></td>
    <td class="concave"/>
    <td class="middle" style="width:25%;">Step 3</td>
    <td style="max-width:0.5em;"><div class="convex"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi add to this in your table `cellpadding="0" border="0"`  like this if you write any table than you also add to this

```
cellpadding="0" border="0" cellspacing="0"
```

```css
.concave{
  border-left:1em solid transparent;
  border-top:1em solid orange;
  border-bottom:1em solid orange;
}

.middle{
  background-color:orange;
}

.convex{
  border-left:1em solid orange;
  border-top:1em solid transparent;
  border-bottom:1em solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="font-size:30px;">
  <tr>
    <td class="concave"/>
    <td class="middle" style="width:25%;">Step 1</td>
    <td style="max-width:0.5em;"><div class="convex"/></td>
    <td class="concave"/>
    <td class="middle" style="width:25%;">Step 2</td>
    <td style="max-width:0.5em;"><div class="convex"/></td>
    <td class="concave"/>
    <td class="middle" style="width:50%;">Step 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Is it necessary to add cellspacing=“0” cellpadding=“0”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078309/is-it-necessary-to-add-cellspacing-0-cellpadding-0-in-table?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve all of your effect using CSS with pseudo elements `::before` and `::after` and only one `td` per "step" in your HTML.

I also removed all the inline CSS!… It's better and easier to have all the CSS in one place.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.step {
  position: relative;
  height: 2em;
  padding: 0 0 0 1.25em;
  background-color: orange;
}

.step:last-of-type {
  width: 50%;
}

.step::before,
.step::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  content: '';
  border: 1em solid transparent;
  border-right: 0;
}

.step::before {
  left: 0;
  border-left-color: white;
}

.step:not(:last-of-type)::after {
  right: 0;
  border-top-color: white;
  border-bottom-color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="step">Step 1</td>
    <td class="step">Step 2</td>
    <td class="step">Step 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope it helps!